# ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat Access violation reading location

Tags: directx-12, direct3d12

```cpp
ID3D12GraphicsCommandList& commandList = *com_ptr;
FLOAT values[4] = { 1,1,1,1 };
commandList.ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat(m_gpuUavHandle, m_cpuUavHandle, m_resource.get(), values, 0, nullptr);
```

I'm getting the following runtime error:

> Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000140

However, `m_cpuUavHandle.ptr` has value `326` which is only 6 bytes after the location of the access violation `320` (=140 in hexidecimal).

Since in Direct3d12 you manually calculate the handle address, it seems that there is room for something to go wrong

```cpp
m_cpuUavHandle = CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_descriptorHeap.get()->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), offset, m_cbvSrvUavDescriptorSize);
```

---

**Edit**:

I succeeded reproducing this in the DirectX 12 samples ([and uploaded it to github](https://github.com/tom-huntington/ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat-Bug)) and this time got a debug message

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat: Specified descriptor handle ptr=0x0000000000000021 points to a descriptor heap type that is CPU write only, so reading it is invalid. UnorderedAccessViewCPUHandle is the issue. [ EXECUTION ERROR #646: INVALID_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE]

Now `m_cpuUavHandle.ptr=33` and the location of the access violation is at 32 (0x0000000000000020 in hexidecimal).

In my main project I think the exception is hit before the debug message is printed due to threading issues.

Now in my main project I'm getting

> Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

which is still six bytes before `m_cpuUavHandle.ptr = 6`, so I'm not sure if this is right

Comment: First enable the Debug Device and look for output. Your 'commandList' is also some kind of specific type because you are not using the ``->`` operator, so what's it's type? If it's a wrapper, make sure the method matches the actual COM type parameter orders.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn It's just a reference `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList& commandList = *com_ptr` I have have at the start of my render loop, make's it easy to pass around to methods of child objects

Comment: Well your cpu handle cannot come from a shader visible heap as the message says, and in your sample on github it is from shader visible heap...

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-clearunorderedaccessviewfloat the Important section

Comment: Yeh I know there's two issues, but fixing that one will not solve the other: `Specified descriptor handle ptr=0x0000000000000021 points to a descriptor heap type that is CPU write only, so reading it is invalid. UnorderedAccessViewCPUHandle is the issue.`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you but the message you quoted is the one I am talking about. CPU write only heap IS shader visible heap.

Comment: @mateeeeeee yes sorry I was also getting `D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat: ClearUnorderedAccessView* methodsare not compatible with Structured Buffers. StructuredByteStride is set to 32 for resource 0x000002DB11511A00:'m_particleBuffer1[0]'. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #1156: CLEARUNORDEREDACCESSVIEW_INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_STRUCTURED_BUFFERS]`

Comment: Have you tried creating other UAV (not the one you are using for RWStructuredBuffer) for that resource, for example with format R32_UINT and clearing with ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint? I guess you could also try R32_FLOAT and ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat. So you would have two uavs for that structured buffer, one for clearing, and another one for writing. You can always also run a compute shader to do clearing.

Comment: @mateeeeeee thanks, I could have never though shader visible heap from the message but I believe you are correct after looking at the docs! I'm now going to understand shader visible heaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/shader-visible-descriptor-heaps

Comment: You can also see the table here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/non-shader-visible-descriptor-heaps

Comment: Yes I should have just created another UAV to get rid of the other error. Running a compute shader to clear UAVs is what I'm doing now, but it's not that scalable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mateeeeee solved this in the comments. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d12/nf-d3d12-id3d12graphicscommandlist-clearunorderedaccessviewfloat) specify that the cpu descriptor must refer to a non-shader visible heap (one created with `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE`).

For me the solution is to just have two identical CBV_SRV_UAV heaps one created with `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC::Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE` for calling ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat and the other created with `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC::Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE` for everything else.

It is important to note that the cpu descriptor and gpu descriptor arguments for ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat  must come from different heaps.

```cpp
auto [cpu, gpu] = resources.AllocateDescriptorHandlePair();
m_uavHandle = gpu;
m_cpuUavHandle = cpu;
resources.D3D12Device().CreateUnorderedAccessView(m_resource.get(), nullptr, &uavDesc, cpu);
if (nonshader_visable)
{
    m_nonshader_visable_descriptor = resources.AllocateNonVisableDescriptorHandle();
    resources.D3D12Device().CreateUnorderedAccessView(m_resource.get(), nullptr, &uavDesc, *m_nonshader_visable_descriptor);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating two different descriptors heaps? How do I tell D3D12 that they are actually referring to the same resources?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I called `CreateUnorderedAccessView` twice apparently.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. I simply need to create another heap descriptor for that. It's working now. But now I wonder whether I need to synchronize the writes from `CreateUnorderedAccessView` with subsequent reads in my shader: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78047962/547231. Maybe you can take a look?!