# How do I correctly use ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat?

Tags: directx-12

I have a 1-dimensional texture declared as `RWTexture1D<float> : register(u1);`. I'm writing to this texture in one ray generation shader and read from it from another. I don't need to read the from the texture on the CPU side.

Before the ray generation shader which writes to it is executed, I need to set all values contained in it to zero. I thought `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat` would be the function which does that.

Now, the heap descriptor is created is creates by the following code:

```
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC desc{};
desc.NumDescriptors = /* ... */;
desc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV;
desc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;

d3d.device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&desc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_descriptor_heap));

D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE handle = m_descriptor_heap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
m_uav_desc_size = d3d.device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
```

And the code for clearing is:

```
    CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE const  gpu_handle{
        m_descriptor_heap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(),
        m_descriptor_heap_size,
        m_uav_desc_size
    };

    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE const  cpu_handle{
        m_descriptor_heap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(),
        m_descriptor_heap_size,
        m_uav_desc_size
    };

    FLOAT const clear_value = 0;
    m_cmd_list->ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat(gpu_handle, cpu_handle, m_texture1d, &clear_value, 0, nullptr);
```

Unfortunately, this gives the following error:

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat:
> Specified descriptor handle ptr=0x0000000000000043 points to a
> descriptor heap type that is CPU write only, so reading it is invalid.
> UnorderedAccessViewCPUHandle is the issue. [ EXECUTION ERROR #646:
> INVALID_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE]

In this post the same problem is described: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72889175/547231.

The answer says that I should create two descriptor heaps; one with `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE`. However, I don't get that. How do I ensure that they point to the same resources? How would I need to modify the code for `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have both shader visible and not visible heap. You create your gpu UAV from shader visible heap, and cpu UAV from not visible heap.

```
CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE const  gpu_handle{
        gpu_descriptor_heap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(),
        gpu_descriptor_heap_size,
        uav_desc_size
    };

    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE const  cpu_handle{
        cpu_descriptor_heap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(),
        cpu_descriptor_heap_size,
        uav_desc_size
    };
```

So you will have 2 heaps, `gpu_descriptor_heap` and `cpu_descriptor_heap`.
`gpu_descriptor_heap` will be created with `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE`, the `cpu_descriptor_heap` with `D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE`.

To ensure they are pointing to the same resource, you can call `CreateUnorderedAccessView` twice, passing in both cases handles from those heaps with `GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart`, or you can call it once for your cpu heap and then call `CopyDescriptors` to copy it to your shader visible heap.