# Simultaneous access to the same pixel in a ray generation shader - is it safe?

Tags: shader, directx, hlsl, raytracing, directx-12

I have a ray generation shader which adds a random number of rgb values to a `RWTexture2D<float3> output : register(u0)` at *random* pixel locations:

```
[shader("raygeneration")]
void foo()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        float2 const raster_point = float2(rand(seed) * width, rand(seed) * height);
        float3 radiance;
        // trace a path starting at raster_point
        // and store the result in radiance.

        tau += /* somehow computed at random */;
        output[uint2(raster_point)] += radiance;

        if (/* exit criterion is met */)
            break;
    }
}
```

`tau` is a global float (don't know how I need to declare it and bind it to a register). Before `output` can be copied to the back buffer and be displayed, I need to divide each element of `output` by `tau`:

```
[shader("compute")]
void bar()
{
    for (uint i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        for (uint j = 0; j < width; ++j)
            output[uint(i, j)] /= tau;
    }
}
```

Now, I have several issues with my concern:

1. How do I set each element of output to `float3(0, 0, 0)` before `foo` is called? I thought this would be possible with `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat`, but [I got trouble using that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78021222/547231). So, do I need to use a compute shader which I execute before and which clears `output` appropriately?
2. I'm calling `DispatchRays` with `width = n` and `height = depth = 1`. Since multiple invocations of `foo` could try to alter `output` at the same index at the same time, I was wondering if this is actually safe. Do I need to switch to some kind of atomic operation (`InterlockedAdd`) here? If so, would it be better to use an array `RWTexture2D<float3> outputs[N]` and call `DispatchRays` with `width = N` instead? Then I would only alter `outputs[DispatchRaysIndex().x]` in the code. I would also need to alter the definition of `foo` to ensure that the resulting code is still invoked `n` times (`n != N`).
3. Do I really need to use a compute shader to get what I do with `bar`? I would also need to sum the outputs in (2.) if I actually should use an array of outputs.

I've tried to answer these questions for a couple of days now, but the docs do not give me any indication of what I should do and which of the described options is preferred.

Comment: 1. You should be able to do it with both ways you mentioned, either ClearUnorderedAccessView or dispatching your own compute shader.
2. Yes you need InterlockedAdd to avoid undefined behaviour, I wouldnt bother with arrays if I were you.
3. How else would you do it if not in compute shader? There is no API function that does that.

Comment: @mateeeeeee Regarding 2.: Isn't `InterlockedAdd` only availabe for integers? https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/HLSL_SM_6_6_Int64_and_Float_Atomics.html#interlockedadd