# How can I use (resource) barriers to sync access to a `RWTexture2D` between different shaders?

Tags: shader, directx, raytracing, directx-12, barrier

Here is my situation: I have a `RWTexture2D<float4> out` which will always be in state `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS` and another `RWTexture2D<float4> tex` (initialized in state `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE`) and my render loop is like this:

1. Clear `out` to zero using `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat`
2. Perform `DispatchRays` which will read from *and* write to `out`
3. Transition `tex` from `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE` to `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS`
4. Invoke a compute shader which transform the values in `out` and stores the result in `tex`
5. Transition `tex` from `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_UNORDERED_ACCESS` to `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_SOURCE`

Currently I'm waiting for the GPU to be finished (by a method of the form `wait_for_gpu` below) after (1.) and again after (2.). I've noticed that the performance of this is rather poor. So my question is: How can I do this better?

I guess it can be made way more efficient by using (resource) barriers. Beyond `ResourceBarrier` there is now another method `Barrier` (see https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/D3D12EnhancedBarriers.html) and I'm quite lost about how I should use them here.

I've tried something like the following:

```
D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER resource_barrier;
resource_barrier.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAG_NONE;
resource_barrier.Type = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE_UAV;
resource_barrier.UAV.pResource = out;
command_list->ResourceBarrier(1, &resource_barrier);
```

But does that really do what I want? I clearly only want to make sure that before the ray generation shader is invoked by `DispatchRays`, the stores from `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat` have finished and it is safe to read those values.

Using `Barrier` instead, it might be better to specify a `D3D12_BARRIER_GROUP` with a `D3D12_TEXTURE_BARRIER` and `SyncBefore = D3D12_BARRIER_SYNC_CLEAR_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW` (though this enum value doesn't seem to be available in my version of `d3d12.h`) and `SyncAfter = D3D12_BARRIER_SYNC_RAYTRACING`.

Unfortunately, I personally think that the documentation is quite poor and I have no idea what would be the best way to use these things here. So, any help is highly appreciated.

---

```
void wait_for_gpu() 
{
    command_queue->Signal(fence, fence_values[frame_index]);

    fence->SetEventOnCompletion(fence_values[frame_index], fence_event);
    WaitForSingleObjectEx(fence_event, INFINITE, FALSE);

    ++d3d.fence_values[frame_index];
}
```

Comment: I stopped reading at #2. Why do you need to do #1 at all? It you initialize `out` to 0 you never need to read from it, just write to `out`

Comment: Because in #2 I add (maybe multiple times to the same location) values to `out`. That is, I don't *set* them, but *add*. That's why I need to set them to 0 before.

Comment: Okay, it's idiomatic to write to group shared memory, to do you computations and then just write to texture memory once at the end

Comment: That looks it should do what you want. I've never used `D3D12_BARRIER_GROUP`. The documentation is not enough, you basically need to copy the patterns from the [ray-tracing sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12Raytracing). Step through the render loop with the debugger to figure out how to use the api

Comment: also you should use PIX, to understand what your program is doing. You should be able answer this question yourself by looking at PIX timings